# User with less than 50 rep making a comment

Tags: support, comments, reputation

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5049420/gamil) user made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049594/why-is-grails-gorm-autoflush-set-to-true-not-working#comment50128785_31049594) comment.
However, he has only 1 rep.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), you still need 50 rep to comment.

I smell a bug, what's going on here?

EDIT: Turns out it's all explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/269301). Case closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely the user posted that as an answer and the system, noting that it was short and a link to a Stack Exchange site, auto-converted it to a comment.

Comment: There is no deleted answer. If the system did this, it converted the answer into a comment on the fly (which would be a great feature).

Comment: Hey, it's [a feature from 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/98955#98955) apparently. I never knew it existed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's the correct answer.